# how to pass the value of parameter in android retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Question Regarding "Retrofit"

i have an api like this `listing/get_listings?listing_type=featured`
in this api i have a parameter `listing_type` ... i am using it like this

```
@GET("listing/get_listings")
    Call<List<ProviderModel>> getProviderListing(@Query("listing_type") String listing_type);
```

now i want to add the value of parameter like this:

```
 RetrofitUtil.createProviderAPI().getProviderListing("featured").enqueue(getProviders(this));
```

but i am not getting response can any one help me how to solve the issue

Comment: what is error coming? check your logcat ...

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: check onError of retrofit. Is there any exception there or not ?

Comment: @SushilKumar issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

add loginterceptor and check the issue

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'


 okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder client = new okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


    client.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(OfflineApi.base_url).client(client.build()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```